# Как хранят данные о цвете фигуры?

Tags: база-данных, uml

Есть объект линия. Должна быть возможность задать и хранить значения цвета линии.
Как я понимаю хранение атрибута как "Цвет линии: String" неправильно.

Как хранят данные о цвете линии/точки и т.п? В каком атрибуте, какой тип атрибута, атрибутов должно быть несколько?

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Хранить можно в десятке разных форматов.

Comment: @Kromster ну вроде бы вопрос ясен, вопрос — в каком из этих десятков форматов хранить) Но, возможно, дать универсальный ответ затруднительно

Comment: @andreymal Очевидно в том, в каком он используется.

Comment: @Dmitry очевидно, если цветов много, а используются они в каком-нибудь виде типа `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.000)`, то хранение в том виде, в каком он используется, может стремительно угробить свободное место на диске, так что не)

Comment: @andreymal А вот это совсем не очевидно. Без описания того, что именно и как хранится в БД, нельзя сказать, сколько места это займет. Если у ТС в базе хранятся объекты, у которых 100 свойств, а цвет - это только одно из них, то это будет экономия на спичках. Если он хранит миллион объектов, 13 байт на цвет дадут всего лишь 13 МБ.

Comment: а можете дать ссылку на материалы где описаны эти десятки форматов хранения данных о цвете?

Comment: @Kirumit Десятки форматов описаны в десятках разных мест. Вы лучше скажите, что вы с этим цветом дальше будете делать и где использовать?

Comment: Все форматы для отображения тем или иным способом сводятся к тому, чтобы закодировать 3 значения для трех цветовых компонентов (и иногда еще один для прозрачности).

Comment: @Dmitry нужно хранить, чтобы потом на карте отобразить линию с указанным цветом

Comment: @Dmitry три значения и 1 для прозрачности. Вот это уже похоже на то что нужно. А три значения. что это за значения?

Comment: @Kirumit https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB

Comment: @Dmitry ваш ответ не могу отметить(

Comment: @Kirumit Ну правильно, это же не ответ, а комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно хранить в виде hex строки (#fffaaa), которое потом, если я не ошибаюсь, принимает множество библиотек для работы с цветом.

Comment: При том, что любой цвет отлично помещается в unsigned int32, использование семи (а иногда даже восьми) байт на строку выглядит расточительством

Comment: @andreymal согласен, можно хранить и в int32, только иногда все же придется конвертировать такое представление перед использованием. Я лишь предложил вариант.